# Parse URL value and remove anything after the last '/'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My website URL is (*example*) `http://mypage.com/en/?site=main`. Then comes JavaScript code that, together with PHP, parses the data.

After that, I need some code that will change the URL **inside the adress bar** to `http://mypage.com/en/`, that is, removes the stuff after the last `/` (slash).

*If possible, it is should be jQuery/JavaScript code.*

Comment: do you want to remove querystrings or remove the stuff after the last `/`?

Comment: You can use parse_url, online doc's are here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Removing the query string in the address bar may affect the way your website displays if it is relying on them.

Comment: @dSquared I would run the removing script after the code that works with the url is done.

Comment: @DJDavid98 any code using JS to replace the URL inside and address bar will inevitably cause the page to reload, which in turn will cause the page not to work as no query string is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that will work.
You have to use a method called `replaceState()`.

[Mozilla developer reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

```
var str = window.location.href;
window.history.replaceState({}, '', str.substr(0,str.lastIndexOf("/"))+"/");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function in javascript.

**Example :**

```
var url = "http://mypage.com/en/?site=main";
alert(url.split('?')[0]);
```

Comment: This will **not** change the URL inside the browser's address bar.